# How does this JavaScript Asynchronous code work?

Tags: javascript

I want to know what is passed to the parameter inside the .then callback function? Is it the resolved value of the getUsers() function.

```js
function getFirstUser() {
  return getUsers().then(function(users) {
    return users[0].name;
  }).catch(function(err) {
    return {
      name: 'default user'
    };
  });
}
```

Comment: yes, it is the resolved value of getUsers()

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Answer (score 2):

> Is it the resolved value of the `getUsers()` function?

Yes, it is. and `err` is the *rejected* value of the `getUsers()` function.

Example:

```js
const promise = Promise.resolve(":)"); // Same as new Promise( res => res(":)") )

promise.then( value => {
  console.log(value); // Logs :)
});
```